# Prevent Django from running contrib tests?

Tags: django, testing

Is there any way to prevent `./manage.py test` from running tests on installed apps like `django.contrib.auth`?

Comment: IIRC `django.contrib` is a directory, not an app.  What tests are in this directory?

Comment: you could just run `./manage.py test appname`

Comment: @S.Lott at very least I'm getting a failure for `test_current_site_in_context_after_login (django.contrib.auth.tests.views.LoginTest)` when I run `./manage.py test`.

Comment: @lazerscience yea, which is what I do while I'm working on one app… But it's annoying that I can't run tests for all my apps easily.

Comment: Ok, for now I'm going to use `django-nose`… But a proper solution would be nice.

Comment: You're testing `django.contrib.auth`.  The `auth` application.  In the `django.contrib` package.  Please update your question.

Comment: is that particular test failure a bug... it seems that everyone not using the sites framework probably gets it

Comment: It's not just django.contrib.auth though, there are a bunch of applications under django.contrib, and 'manage.py test' seems to run tests from several of them, about 200 tests in all.  None of them fail for me, but I'd rather increase the speed of my test run by not running them every time. Are they really likely to start failing sometime? I don't run the Python core tests every time I run my project tests.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing a custom test runner for my project, which walks the project tree, imports all the modules, iterates through classes in each module, looking for subclasses of unittest.TestCase, and adds them all to a TestSuite, then runs them. This way, I can filter out the django.contrib ones, and also include some of my own unittest.TestCases which manage.py ignores (because they aren't in myapp/tests.py, etc)

I only just wrote it and it's doubtless full of errors, but to date, this is what it looks like:

```
from inspect import getmembers, isclass
import os
from os.path import join, relpath
import sys
from unittest import TestCase, TestLoader, TestSuite, TextTestRunner

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
from django.test.utils import setup_test_environment

sys.path.append('..')


def import_module(modname):
    print modname
    try:
        __import__(modname)
        return sys.modules[modname]
    except Exception as e:
        print
        print '    %s: %s' % (type(e).__name__, e)


def get_modules(root):
    for subdir, dirs, fnames in os.walk(root):
        for fname in fnames:
            if fname.endswith('.py'):
                path = relpath(join(subdir, fname))
                modname = path.replace('/', '.')[:-3]
                if modname.endswith('__init__'):
                    modname = modname[:-9]
                if modname == '':
                    continue
                yield import_module(modname)


def get_testcases(module):
    for name, value in getmembers(module):
        if isclass(value) and issubclass(value, TestCase) and value is not TestCase:
            print '  ', name, value
            yield value


def main():
    setup_test_environment()

    testcases = set()
    for module in get_modules(os.getcwd()):
        for klass in get_testcases(module):
            testcases.add(klass)
    print 'found %d testcases' % (len(testcases),)

    suite = TestSuite()
    for case in testcases:
        suite.addTest(TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(case))

    print 'loaded %d tests' % (suite.countTestCases(),)
    TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the proper solution is as lazerscience said:

```
python manage.py test appname appname.SomeTestCase appname.TestCase.test_method
```

When you just [run test command](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#id1) all apps in INSTALLED_APPS will be tested including those from contrib (such as auth, admin, sites etc).

Also if some test are failing it means something doesn't work properly, you should rather fix the problem then hide the failing test. If Django tests are failing make sure you are using stable release version.

Comment: As I replied to lazerscience: that doesn't make it any easier to test all, say, 10 of my site's custom applications at once :(